# Does Notepad++ have DOM navigator/HTML tree view

Tags: treeview, notepad++

I really like Notepad++, but sometimes the script gets hard to navigate. I searched for a plugin that shows DOM like Espresso Navigator (http://657b072aab060d50f8ce-d7abb53cb376b4947d77643d4b4a48d3.r79.cf1.rackcdn.com/2137_69d6dc6e.png), but didn't find anything.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 bits that might help you navigate. They certainly help me with complex scripts.

The left margin can display the tree and allow folding or collapsing certain html elements. This is a good navigation tool to 'hide' whole tags to focus on certain bits of the code.

To see this tree, go to Settings / Preferences / Editing tab / Folder Margin Style / and set anything other than 'none'. I prefer the Box Tree myself. In this mode (and perhaps others as well) the line down the left margin goes red to cover all lines within that tag.

Naturally, you will have the language for the file selected as HTML or Javascript or whatever your editing.

To hide a whole div (say) click the + in the margin beside the div tag and it is collapsed.

Now to help read the document and to help the folding tree to work its best, then use the TextFX HTML Tidy to format the code in a way that suites you.

If working on someone else's scripts that are poorly formatted and complex, I sometimes even start with HTML Tidy, then use the folding tree to find out whats going on.

Comment: Tnx, that's useful and I've used it before. Also Alt+0 to close all tags and Shift+0 to open all tags is handy, but still it's not quite the navigator.

Comment: It will be interesting to see if anyone else turns up a navigator equivalent for NP++. If you find one, please post back here so we can check it out. I'll do the same.